# How to correctly use Python list comprehension?

Tags: python, matrix, list-comprehension

```html
step["args"][1][base + i for i in range(31)] = True
```

Why I get an invalid syntax error?
I would like to use a list comprehension in python in order to not write:

```html
step["args"][1][base + 1] = True
step["args"][1][base + 2] = True
step["args"][1][base + 3] = True
step["args"][1][base + 4] = True
step["args"][1][base + 5] = True
...
step["args"][1][base + 30] = True
```

Comment: What are `step` / `base`? Can you provide a [mcve]? In any case, list comprehensions should *not* be used for assigning values, they should be used for creating lists.

Comment: list comps are for building lists, not assignments, use `for i in range(31): step["args"][1][base + i] = True`

Comment: @jpp It's not important.
base is a number, e.g. base=10

Comment: Also what is `step` and the other nested objects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[base + i for i in range(31)]
```

evaluates into:

```
[0, 1, 2, ..., 30]
```

So you're trying to slice something with a length-31 list.

You can't easily achieve what you're trying to do with a list comprehension (They don't do assignment).

You need a for loop:

```
for i in range(31):
    step["args"][1][base + i] = True
```

Comment: Yep, the issue is that you are trying to use a list comprehension to assign values to the original list. However the list comprehension returns a new list so even if assignment worked it would be completely pointless as a the original list would be left unchanged.

Comment: Thanks!! You've understood perfectly what I need

Comment: Exactly.  The word "comprehension" means a specific _understanding_ of something, in this case, of a list, dict, or similar.  So a comprehension is a _rule_ on how to _create_ a list, etc.  It is not a variable you could assign something to.

Comment: The meaning of "comprehension" here is more closely related to the definition of "comprehensive" than to "understanding".

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to assign `True` to a range of "slots" in an existing list:

```
from itertools import repeat

step["args"][1][base+1:base+31] = repeat(True, 30)
```